# php while loop inside of while loop - need joins?

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop

Ok, so i am working on some software where users can submit tickets for bugs found on a website.  I am using multiple checkboxes so users can check all browsers that are affected by the bug.  The bug `bugId`, `title`, `type`, etc are stored in one table called `bugs` and the affected browsers are stored in another table called `affectedbrowsers`.  The commonality between the two tables is the `bugId`.  I have the form submitting everything correctly.

My problem is returning the data.  I have an html table that has one row for each bug in the `bugs` database table.  There is one column called "Affected Browsers" that i would like to populate with the data from the `affectedbrowsers` table.  I tried using a while loop to loop through the bugs and echo out the rows in the html table and using a second while loop within that first while loop that would query the `affectedbrowsers` table and find all the records that have the same `bugId`.  This isn't returning any data in the second while loop.  I would like to use `JOINS` if possible but i am not really familiar with them.  What are your thoughts?

My Code:

```
<?php
    echo "<table>";
    $resultBug = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE projectId = '$projectId' ORDER BY bugId ASC");
    echo "<tr> <th>Case Title</th> <th>Affected Browsers</th> </tr>";
    while($rowBug = mysql_fetch_array( $resultBug )){
        $bugId = $_POST['bugId'];
        echo "<tr><td>";
        $rowBugTitle = htmlspecialchars($rowBug['title']);
        echo $rowBugTitle;
        echo "</td><td>";
        $resultAffectedBrowsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affectedbrowsers WHERE bugId = '$bugId' ORDER BY id ASC");
        while($rowAffectedBrowsers = mysql_fetch_array( $resultAffectedBrowsers )){
            $affectedBrowsers = $rowAffectedBrowsers['label'];
            echo $affectedBrowsers . " - ";
        }
        echo "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get the browsers for the current bug, so you should have

```
$bugID = $rowBug['bugId'];
```

instead of

```
$bugID = $_POST['bugId'];
```

Comment: wow...i feel a little dumb for that one....guess i've just been starring at it for too long.  That worked. Thanks!  Glad it was an easy fix

Answer (score 1):

Do not execute query inside the loop - use joins instead.

```
 SELECT b.bugId, b.title, ab.label FROM bugs b
 INNER JOIN affectedbrowsers ab
 ON ab.bugId = b.bugId
 WHERE b.projectId = '$projectId' ORDER BY b.bugId, ab.id ASC
```

Also do not mix the HTML and PHP - at least move the query to separate function and rendering  to another function.

And sanitize the input - do not put the _POST variable directly into query.

Comment: If the OP changes to loops, it will affect all of his looping logic. You should identify how it will change since the OP clearly stated they're not familiar with `JOIN`s. For example, the new recordset will have multiple rows for each bug (assuming multiple browsers) and will have no records for bugs where there were no affected browsers (assuming that's possible).

Answer (score 1):

On top of @AlexAtNet suggestion, I would add [grouping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) so that each bug is returned only once (even when multiple browsers are affected)

```
SELECT b.bugId, b.title, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ab.label ORDER BY ab.label ASC SEPARATOR ' - ') AS browsers 
FROM bugs b
INNER JOIN affectedbrowsers ab ON ab.bugId = b.bugId
WHERE b.projectId = '$projectId'
GROUP BY b.bugId
ORDER BY b.bugId ASC
```

The result would look like

```
bugId | title       | browsers
------+-------------+-----------------------
1     | "Bug-one"   | "Chrome - IE"
2     | "Bug-2"     | "Firefox"
3     | "Bug-three" | "Chrome - Safari - IE"
```